# How to slide to Right in JSSOR plugin

Tags: jquery, jssor

I had made a slider with 8 small images and enabled `autoPlay` but with that the direction still right to left So how to reverse the motion to (left to right)

tried editing `_PlayDirection` but with no result

```
var nestedSliders = [];
    var jssor_sliderh;
    $.each(["sliderh1_container", "sliderh2_container"], function(index, value) {

        var sliderhOptions = {
            $AutoPlay: true, //[Optional] Whether to auto play, to enable slideshow, this option must be set to true, default value is false
            $PauseOnHover: 1, //[Optional] Whether to pause when mouse over if a slider is auto playing, 0 no pause, 1 pause for desktop, 2 pause for touch device, 3 pause for desktop and touch device, default value is 1
            $AutoPlaySteps: 1, //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request (this options applys only when slideshow disabled), the default value is 1
            $SlideDuration: 1000, //[Optional] Specifies default duration (swipe) for slide in milliseconds, default value is 500
            $MinDragOffsetToSlide: 20, //[Optional] Minimum drag offset to trigger slide , default value is 20
            $SlideWidth: 89, //[Optional] Width of every slide in pixels, default value is width of 'slides' container
            $SlideHeight: 90, //[Optional] Height of every slide in pixels, default value is height of 'slides' container
            $SlideSpacing: 3, //[Optional] Space between each slide in pixels, default value is 0
            $DisplayPieces: 8, //[Optional] Number of pieces to display (the slideshow would be disabled if the value is set to greater than 1), the default value is 1
            $ParkingPosition: 0, //[Optional] The offset position to park slide (this options applys only when slideshow disabled), default value is 0.
            $UISearchMode: 0, //[Optional] The way (0 parellel, 1 recursive, default value is 1) to search UI components (slides container, loading screen, navigator container, arrow navigator container, thumbnail navigator container etc).
            $DragOrientation: 0,
            $BulletNavigatorOptions: {//[Optional] Options to specify and enable navigator or not
                $Class: $JssorBulletNavigator$, //[Required] Class to create navigator instance
                $ChanceToShow: 2, //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
                $AutoCenter: 0, //[Optional] Auto center navigator in parent container, 0 None, 1 Horizontal, 2 Vertical, 3 Both, default value is 0
                $Steps: 1, //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request, default value is 1
                $Lanes: 1, //[Optional] Specify lanes to arrange items, default value is 1
                $SpacingX: 0, //[Optional] Horizontal space between each item in pixel, default value is 0
                $SpacingY: 0, //[Optional] Vertical space between each item in pixel, default value is 0
                $Orientation: 1                                 //[Optional] The orientation of the navigator, 1 horizontal, 2 vertical, default value is 1
            }
        };
        jssor_sliderh = new $JssorSlider$(value, sliderhOptions);
        if (index === 1) { // if second slider since I have two Horzontial sliders with reverse motion
            jssor_sliderh.$On($JssorSlider$.$EVT_STATE_CHANGE, function(slideIndex, progress, progressBegin, idleBegin, idleEnd, progressEnd)
            {
                setTimeout(
                        function()
                        {
                            jssor_sliderh.$PlayTo(slideIndex - 1);
                        }, 3000);
            });
        }

        nestedSliders.push(jssor_sliderh);
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good to know the requirements and thanks for the good question.
I have just fixed $JssorSlider$.$EVT_STATE_CHANGE event trigger and updated downloads.
Please download the latest version.

Please set $AutoPlay to false and use api call to reach your goals.

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        var options = {
            $AutoPlay: false,
            $DragOrientation: 3
        };

        var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container", options);

        jssor_slider1.$On($JssorSlider$.$EVT_STATE_CHANGE, function (slideIndex, progress, progressBegin, idleBegin, idleEnd, progressEnd)
        {
            if(progress == progressEnd)
            {
                //play to previous slide when a slide plays over
                jssor_slider1.$PlayTo(slideIndex - 1);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your wonderful plugin and wonderful answer, But I have an issue of time I specfied ``$SlideDuration`` in options But the motion of ``jssor_slider1.$PlayTo`` is quiet faster what the cause of that I updated the question of fully code I'm using and solution to this problem I tried and it works yet the plugin should use ``$SlideDuration``

Comment: and one more thing when I hover on it, The slider doesn't stop which is not accepted behavior while the other slider stops normally thanks in advance :)

Comment: I really suggest you make as an option in  ``$JssorSlider$`` options

Comment: $PlayOrientation option updated, please download the latest version. [Optional] Orientation to play slide (for auto play, navigation), 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 5 horizental reverse, 6 vertical reverse, default value is 1.